# Amazon Product Advertisng API - Workaround to get more than 100 items from ItemSearch? TotalVotes response group?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I'm wondering if there's a way of using the advertising API to get info on the top 5000 or so by rank. I was thinking I could get multiple searches from say $0.10 intervals. And then my hope is to parse the XML into a CSV.

Also does anyone know what parameter will give me the TotalVotes response group from an ItemSearch?